# Boost converting 0.5V PV output to charge a super capacitor

Tags: solar-cell, boost, supercapacitor

I want to charge three 2.5V 700F [super capacitors](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/dl-dle-e-140101.pdf) in series (7.5V total) to a precise 6V so that I [avoid overcharging](https://www.instructables.com/Lets-learn-about-Super-Capacitors-A-Practical-G/) a single capacitor in the string. (Conservative 80% voltage to avoid having to balance the capacitors in the bank.)

I would like to use a PV power source for this.

Typically, PV panels will put many 0.5V PV cells in series to get a much higher voltage like 18V.

But is it possible to use the PV cells in parallel instead, and just boost their 0.5V to my required 6V? (Or alternatively, put maybe 4 PV cells in series, and boost the resulting 2V to a 6V?)

I would like to avoid using a PV panel that has varying voltage that can possibly be too high, at times, for the 6V charge of the super capacitors. I cannot afford occasional spikes from a 12 cell 6V panel.)

Or would buck converting an 18V panel down to 6V be the way to go here?

Answer (score 1):

With all the PWM modules that exist nowadays, I can hardly imagine a better, cheaper and more efficient solution than something like this:

[DC-DC 1.3-36V 5A Digital Voltage Regulator Module XL4015E1](https://www.banggood.com/XH-M291-DC-DC-1_3-36V-5A-Digital-Voltage-Regulator-Module-XL4015E1-Switch-Type-Voltage-Regulator-Circuit-Board-p-1913963.html?cur_warehouse=CN&rmmds=search)

Still, I would also include in this contraption, a balancing circuit for there are no guaranty that one capacitor will not end-up with more charge than its neighbor which could be catastrophic for that capacitor.

[image: Regulator and Balancer]
The MJE700 transistors will need to be slightly heatsinked to some metal part (using an isolation mica and heat paste).  You can also utilize some power PNP transistor with a simple PNP 2N3906 to build the Darlington configuration. The 10k and 6k resistors are calculated for a 4 Volts regulation. 4 Volts distributed into 2 series capacitors will ensure 2 volts per capacitor. Two regulators will warrant 2 Volts per capacitor for the third regulator is the PWM module adjusted to 6 Volts.

Also, you could disable the LED digital display for sake of saving power.

Utilizing 3 regulators instead of two would have been more elegant but not possible with the LM431 regulator which is locked at 2.5V.  Still, this arrangement is adequate. I've used it for power distribution on a 4 Lithium cells power module. It's been working for years now and my batteries are quite OK up to this moment.